# Azure AKS - Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=masterclient, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

Tags: azure-aks

I have two AKS installed, in both
Suddenly  I'm getting this Error

Waiting: ImagePullBackOff
POD Log: Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=masterclient, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

I have my acr connected fine with aks. Added roles for aks in acr again. BTW the error occurs on some random pod in the scale. e.g. if scalling is 9 pods, it may fail at 7.
Its also happening while installing kafka. so its not just my container registry.

Comment: Solved it by upgrading kubernetes to latest version in azure. Downside, had to redeploy everything.